# How to relocate the code belong to SRAM instead of Flash on TriCore Microcontroller

Tags: embedded, bootloader

I'm currently trying to solve a problem which requires erasing, update new Custom Bootloader (CBL) memory area when it's running on the CBL region

The CBL allowed upgrading new application and it has worked normally.
Sometimes I need to update new CBL. I can't modify the flash memory when CBL's running
From the application I can jump back to CBL address for updating Application as below picture

[image]

According to my understanding, Microcontroller shall run directly the binary code which saved on flash of CBL. So, we can't erase or write the current area memory, is that correct?

Do u have any idea to solve it such as relocate the function by  linker file to execute on SRAM instead of Flash ..etc?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Which procedures did you investigate already, and why did they not work for you? Recommendations are off-topic here... Can't the system bootloader flash your CBL? Did you try to run a CBL flasher from RAM? What measure do you take if the update of the CBL fails?

Comment: Can't the system bootloader flash your CBL?
-> I want to update CBL rom application jump back to CBL. It mean that update new CBL when CBL is executing
I can flash CBL from system bootloader, but It's belong to another physical port.
When the application is executing, I can switch back to CBL, can't jump into System bootloader. That's main reason I need to update both CBL and App from current CBL

Comment: Did you try to run a CBL flasher from RAM?
-> I've approached this way, but not success yet. Could you tell me how relocate the code into RAM memory, It mean that run directly RAM to erase, write into Flash?

Comment: What measure do you take if the update of the CBL fails?
-> In worst case, if CBL was fault, It shall run the CBL backup or copy backup data into CBL

Comment: Please add new information by [edit]ing your question, comments are not supposed to hold clarifications. This is not a forum. -- You already have the right idea to use the linker file to allocate this update procedure to RAM. You might want to add a [mre] to demonstrate the difficulties you have. -- So you need to have two independent CBLs, and a method to let SBL (system BL) select the correct one. If you have two CBLs, does your MCU organize its flash in independent segments? Please add more information.